# access data/files from outside network

Tags: active-directory, remote-access

We need our users (6000+) to be able to access files from their "home" and "shared" drives outside of our AD network.

We have considered VPN or global connect solutions, but these are too complicated for most of our users. (teachers and students) We also use Google Docs extensively, but we need something that can handle more file types.

What is everyone using for file/data access outside the network? Needs to be secure as some data is sensitive.

We used to use Novell Webaccess, but killed it when we recently switched to Microsoft AD. Currently we have nothing in place and our users are clamoring for dropbox type services. We are reticent to go this direction due to student data concerns.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [stoneware](http://www.stone-ware.com/site/index.html), they do offer a solution to a problem like this.  I haven't really played with it much though, just saw a presentation.

Answer (score 0):

We use Sharepoint to accomplish this. It's not as easy as going to their home folder to access their docs, but it provides version control and a central point of management for backup purposes. (The average user rarely thinks to backup that super important spreadsheet)

Making Sharepoint accessible via the web only requires that they use their Domain Credentials to connect. Microsoft has been trying to make Sharepoint price competitive for organizations of all sizes too, so it may not be as expensive as you think.

I sound like a Microsoft guy I'm sure, but I swear I don't work for them. :-)

Comment: Sharepoint is worth considering, but that would likely turn into a huge culture change. Even though we just switched to AD we have wanted to avoid getting fully into bed with MS.